# How to add custom variables to inventory group synced via AWS?

Tags: ansible

I'm running Ansible Automation Platform. I have an inventory that uses AWS EC2 as a source. I have it automatically create a group for each platform (Linux, Windows, etc) using this:

```yaml
keyed_groups:
  - key: platform
    prefix: aws
```

So this means if one of the instances has `"platform": "windows"`, when the inventory syncs it'll create the `aws_windows` group (if it doesn't exist) and add the instance to that group.

This works great, but I need to add custom connection variables for the Windows hosts that are different from Linux hosts (e.g.: `ansible_connection: winrm`). So I've added those variables to the `aws_windows` group and again everything is working great.

The problem comes in when, for whatever reason, there are 0 instances that get synced (like if I terminate them). In the source I have the setting enabled to 'Overwrite', which cleans the inventory of hosts that no longer exists. So when the inventory syncs, it deletes all the instances and the groups along with them. When I re-create the instance and sync again, it creates the host and the group but now the custom variables I added to the group previously are gone.

I don't want to remove the 'Overwrite' setting because I don't want a number of old, invalid hosts cluttering up the inventory, but I also want to ensure that the custom group variables remain or are replaced when the group is re-created.

So how would I go about this?